# Error when create event series in Salesforce with REST API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, recurring-events

I tried to create event series in Salesforce with Rest API but got error:

> [{'errorCode': 'INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE', 'fields':
>   ['Recurrence2PatternStartDate', 'Recurrence2PatternTimeZone',
>   'Recurrence2PatternVersion', 'Recurrence2PatternText',
>   'IsRecurrence2'], 'message': 'Unable to create/update fields:
>   Recurrence2PatternStartDate, Recurrence2PatternTimeZone,
>   Recurrence2PatternVersion, Recurrence2PatternText, IsRecurrence2.
>   Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is
>   read/write for your profile or permission set.'}]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I also encountered this problem today, and after searching for a long time, I have no idea. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: I tried these fields and works for me. Hope it helpful.
"IsRecurrence": true,
"RecurrenceEndDateOnly": recurrenceEndDate,
"RecurrenceStartDateTime": startDateTime,
"RecurrenceType": "RecursDaily",
"RecurrenceInterval": 1,